# Python generator to lazy read large csv files and shuffle the rows

Tags: python, csv, random, generator

I will like to write a function that yields shuffled rows of a csv file that is too large to fit in memory (~25 million rows).

How can I build a generator to yield data row by row, but not in the same order as they appear in the csv file?

Is it possible to randomize/shuffle the rows in a lazy generator function?

```
def readCSV(csvname, shuffle=True):

    for row in open(csvname, "r"):
        if shuffle:
            # Do something to shuffle the order of the rows
            # But I dont' know how to do this.
        yield row
```

Comment: How large?  You can't shuffle until all the records are in memory.  Do they all fit?

Comment: For the shuffling either look for a built in function, or as an exercise you could use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @TimRoberts If it's too big for the memory, we could do external shuffling, similar to external sorting.

Comment: @SuperbRain And how can I do external shuffle

Comment: @JafetGado For example by using external sorting, sorting by random numbers you attach to the rows.

Comment: @TimRoberts Too large to fit into memory (~25 million rows). I would like the generator to read row by row, but not in the same order as they appear in the csv file. Is it possible to randomize/shuffle the rows in the lazy generator?

Comment: How large is the file, how large are the rows, and how much memory do you have?

Comment: Btw, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @superbrain Because the output of the generator will be fed into a neural network, and it is important to have variation in the data flow in each epoch.

Answer (score 3):

You could read `count` random rows from the file by first creating an index for the large CSV file. This would only need to be done once unless the data is changed. The index would contain the offsets into the file of where all the newlines are.

A random row can then easily be read in by first seeking to the required offset and reading one row in.

For example:

```
import random
import csv
import os
import io

def create_index(index_filename, csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as f_csv:
        index = 1
        line_indexes = []       # Use [0] if no header
        linesep = ord(os.linesep[-1])
        
        while True:
            block = f_csv.read(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE * 1000)
            
            if block:
                block_index = 0
                line_indexes.extend(offset + index for offset, c in enumerate(block) if c == linesep)
                index += len(block)
            else:
                break
                
    with open(index_filename, 'w') as f_index:
        f_index.write('\n'.join(map(str, line_indexes)))


def get_rows(count, index_filename, csv_filename):
    sys_random = random.SystemRandom()
    
    with open(index_filename) as f_index:
        line_indexes = list(map(int, f_index.read().splitlines()))

    row_count = len(line_indexes)
    
    with open(csv_filename) as f_csv:
        for _ in range(count):
            line_number = sys_random.randint(0, row_count-1)
            f_csv.seek(line_indexes[line_number])
            
            if line_number == row_count - 1:
                line = f_csv.read()
            else:
                line = f_csv.read(line_indexes[line_number + 1] - line_indexes[line_number])
            
            yield line_number, next(csv.reader(io.StringIO(line)))


index_filename = 'index.txt'
csv_filename = 'input.csv'

create_index(index_filename, csv_filename)  # only needed ONCE

for row_number, row in get_rows(10, index_filename, csv_filename):
    print(f"Row {row_number}  {row}")
```

The same idea could be used to read from a random starting row or read in a shuffled order.

Obviously seeking back and forth is not going to be as fast as reading the file sequentially but it should be a lot faster than reading from the start.